# Ionic multiple google maps are greyed on IOS device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, angular-google-maps

in my Ionic 6 application running under capacitor, i'm using angular googleMaps component.
I need to use this map component in **several pages** of my application.

In my browser, everything works fine.
When i run the app on my IOS physical device, the map is correctly displayed in the first page.
**But, when i navigate to other page with the same googleMap component, the map is displayed greyed out**.
When i touch the map, the grey disappears and the map is correctly displayed.

In Google Cloud Console, i resticted the API key to some http urls ( not to an IOS app because of ionic ) but this does not solve the issue.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thanks